# What is the interpreter really seeing and executing for bitwise operators?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) in Python 2.7 (`<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `~` and `^`), so my question is: what is the interpreter really seeing and executing? When:

```
>>> 3 >> 0
3
>>> 3 >> 1
1
```

and why

```
>>> 3 >> 2
0
```

and after that if you increment the second number by one the answer will continue to be `0`.

They treat it as if it were a string of bits, written in twos-complement binary. But I do not understand what happens here.

Comment: I have no idea what your question *means*. What on earth does *"what is the interpreter really seeing and executing"* mean? *"They treat it as if it were a string of bits, written in twos-complement binary"* - because **that's what it really is**, in the computer's memory, the integer representation `3` is just for the reader's convenience.

Comment: 3 is 0011 (assuming 4 bits),  0011 shifted right by 1 is 0001, which is.. 1.

Comment: Thank you for answers Maroun Maroun , pascalhein and Michael Lazlo it is very clear for me now. and jonrsharpe thank you for not understanding my question and still try to give an answer ( i do not know you can give an answer when you have no idea about the question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the binary representation of these numbers and imagine that there are infinite zeroes to the left:

```
...0000011 = 3
```

Now, what `>>` does is it shifts the binary representation to the right. This is the same as deleting the last digits:

If you shift by `0` places, nothing changes. Therefore, `3 >> 0` is 3.

If you shift by `1` place, you delete the last binary digit:

```
...0000011 >> 1 = ...000001 = 1
```

Therefore, `3 >> 1` is 1.

If you shift by `2` or more places, all of the binary ones will be deleted and you are left with only zeroes:

```
...0000011 >> 2 = ...00000 = 0
```

This is why `3 >> 2` (or more than 2) is always 0.

Comment: Thank you for answers  Maroun Maroun , pascalhein and Michael Lazlo it is very clear for me now. and  jonrsharpe thank you for not understanding my question and still try to give an answer ( i do not know you can give an answer when you have no idea about the question)